# How do I track down a problem with the latest Java update?

Tags: java

A new Java update, Java 8 Update 261 (8u261), hit us and an app we use here at work stopped working, namely [this one here](https://daisy.org/activities/software/pipeline-2/download-and-installation/).

The application itself issues no warning messages but just stops. If I run it via the command line interface all I get is `...returned non-zero exit status 1`. Not so informative.
It has run for years and years with no problem like this.

I realize this is not much to go on, I'm mainly looking for some pointers on where/how to start tracking down something like this and try and fix it. Maybe there's some usual suspects. I hardly ever touch any Java so I need all the help I can get. Thanks.

Edit: We use Windows 10, btw.

Comment: Any luck contacting the devs already?

Comment: From the website: "The minimum required version is Java is 11"

Comment: @Zabuzard: Nope, I might try that tomorrow.

Comment: @Sasha Frinken: Thats right, but also says "Windows and Mac users do not have to worry about Java because it is included in the DAISY Pipeline installation". Anyway, its been running for years and years and only now breaks with this last update.

Comment: Is the output actually `...returned non-zero exit status 1`, or did you cut it down from a long stack trace trying to make it more easily consumable? If it is larger it would be best to include more/all of it. If it's massive you can always share it through a third-party service like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/), Google Drive, or etc.

Comment: @l3l_aze: It is actually all. What I cut out is just the call itself with a long list of .jar-files for the classpath,

Comment: That's interesting. IDK this company at all but a quick search said that their product "Ace" will exit like this if there's an error while executing, and points to [the configuration documentation](https://daisy.github.io/ace/docs/config/) which tells how to set it up to exit with "2" if it's a problem with the publication along with setting up logging to a file which may help identify the issue.

Comment: @l3l_aze: Thanks. It's a place to start digging.

Comment: Very welcome. I'm sorry it wasn't more definitive, but good luck! We're rooting for you :)